# AOP and Applying Security to UI Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, aop

I'm working on an application in which we are trying hard to keep Separation of Concerns as strongly as possible. We're finding that the cross-cutting concern of security creates a number of complications.

However, it looks like these can be mitigated using attributes and Aspect-Oriented Programming.

I understand it as far as applying aspects to domain layer code, but what if you want to apply it to UI elements? For instance, what if I don't want to display a button when a user does not have permission to execute that functionality?

In our MVC application, at this point we'd have to write (pseudo-code follows):

```
<% if (user.CanSeeSomeData) { <%=Html.TextBox("MyTextBox") } %>
```

But we'd like to control the display with attributes a la AOP if possible.

Any ideas?

Also, if there are 3rd party, open-source tools that would be useful, those suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that a view shouldn't contain much programming (or nothing at all). The idea of using AOP (or a la AOP) in a place where the P is forbidden doesn't look nice.

Let's design it in a different way. Usually views have some control keywords to do the basic stuff: conditions and loops. More intelligence and I'd say that you're mixing the controller role there.

So the `if (user.CanSeeSomeData)` you put there, if it is in fact a simple flag. It's the way views should be.

When you were building the modelview object (the container where you put the information for the view). You could have used AOP to initialize/set that information with a nice attribute in that property for example.

You could ask for attributes instead of "ifs"

```
[UserCanSeeData]
<%=Html.TextBox("MyTextBox") %>
```

This looks like syntactic sugar, not real AOP. Any attempt to say that UserCanSeeData should have more than an if (like a database access to check user priviledges), is an attempt to move controller code into the view.

Comment: thanks for the response, graffic. So, are you saying that the attribute approach is OK, but should be done in the Conroller/ViewModel, or are you saying the if statement is the way to do it *["It's the way views should be"]*

Comment: Also, how would you accomplish this in the ViewModel? I could put an attribute on a property but that doesn't translate into showing/hiding/disabling form items. Are you saying that I *shouldn't*  be trying to hide controls at all, but just handle access violations in the ViewModel/Controller?